# Retrieve vector of vector according to contained type

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am working on a small 3D engine, and I was wondering how to avoid looping through my whole hierarchy (models, lights) each time to access lights, materials, etc...

I decided to create a singleton DataProvider, keeping all the lists, the list of pointers to materials, or list of pointers to lights, any list of type.

However, my code looks too intrusive, each time I have to add a new list, I have to add it to the class attributes.

I finally decided to do something like:

```
class DataProvider
{
  public:
    using DataListContainer = std::vector<std::vector<boost::any>>;
    ...
private:
   DataListContainer data_;
```

The problem that I am copping to is to get the inner vector according to a given type? The whole process here seems to be messy.
In addition to this, using the `boost::any` type can not really guaranty that the type inside the inner vector is unique, it could be mixed.
What would be the proper way to store a vector of vectors, retrieving inner vectors according to the type they store?

Comment: Consider a [template <class T> std::vector<T> data](https://bannalia.blogspot.de/2014/05/fast-polymorphic-collections.html).

Comment: @nwp: That only allows a container of a single type, though (unless `T` in your example is some composite). It appears OP wants a heterogeneous container like `tuple`

Comment: @AndyG It allows any number of types.

Comment: @nwp: It can be instantiated with only one type, though. You'd need a different vector for each type. OP wants 1 container with many types held within, and vector cannot do that.

Comment: I don't want to instanciate it, the provider is going to be a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want, you may use something like:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class DataProviderT
{
public:
    using DataListContainer = std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...>;

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T>& GetVector() { return std::get<std::vector<T>>(data_); }

private:
   DataListContainer data_;
};

using DataProvider = DataProviderT<Model, Light>;
```

Comment: I did not thought about this one. The only problem is that it is still intrusive in the way that I have to update the template. But anyway, it is still a better solution!